# Does the ADO.NET Entity Framework Support Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework

Well does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 SP1 [supports Entity Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx). Moreover, this blog post claims the [Entity Framework supports CF in Visual Studio Entity Designer](http://jmayo.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5F243997972597CE!568.entry?sa=96108136).

However, I couldn't find any way to create new .edmx file. And while I could open the Entity Designer after copying and .edmx from another project, and get the model of my database, I couldn't get it to compile.

So, I would say that Entity Framework does not support CF yet.

Comment: it seems that in fact entity framework does not support cf.. pitty.